# Finding disjoint paths between any number of cell pair marked in nXn matrix

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matrices

**What should be algorithm to find all the disjoint paths between any number of pairs of cells given in matrix?**

We will say two paths will not intersect if there there is no cell common between any two paths.

***My approach is :*** I will pick first cell pair and create a path between them. Now it will work as obstacle for path between other cell pairs. **But problem is how to first pick which cell pair?** Because it will create problem in finding path between some cell pair in future.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. The choice of a path rules out the existence of other ones (and there is even a path which rules out the existence of any other path). I suppose what you really want to do is *maximize* the number of disjoint paths. If that is the case, please mention it in the answer.

Comment: @dkaeae I have a fixed number of cells given but pair is not fixed. It is upto us which cell we pick to make path between other given cell.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot make sense of this. What is given? What can you choose? What are you supposed to do? The question would (greatly) benefit from a formal description of the problem.

Comment: @dkaeae You're given a (full) grid graph and disjoint sets $S$ and $T$ of vertices with $|S|=|T|$ and you have to find a set of $|S|$ vertex-disjoint $S$-$T$ paths. (Or, possibly, you're told which $S$ vertex should be linked to which $T$ vertex; it shouldn't make much difference.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Aha, so this is simply [Menger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem) restricted to matrices?

Comment: @dkaeae Seems to be, yes. Only we need to actually find the paths, rather than just proving that they exist. According to Tali Eilam-Tzoreff ([_The disjoint shortest paths problem_](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X97001212), _Discrete Applied Mathematics_ 85(2):113-138, 1998), it's **NP**-complete for general graphs, though it may well be easier for grids.